# How to check hardware compatibility for Mac Mini before upgrading to Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, upgrade, osx-leopard

I am using a Mac Mini (having a light white logo – an older Mac Mini model). It is using Leopard 10.5.8. I want to upgrade to 10.6.8.

I want to check **is it possible to install?**
If it is possible, then I will start downloading the combo upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snow Leopard [needs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Snow_Leopard#System_requirements) a …

> Mac computer with an **Intel processor** (IA-32).
>
> - "Yonah" processors such as **Core Solo** and **Core Duo** can run only 32-bit applications;
> - later x86-64 architecture processors such as **Core 2 Duo** will also be able to run 64-bit applications.

Additional requirements are 1GB of RAM and a DVD drive. More than 1GB of RAM would be preferred though (from my personal experience). See also Snow Leopard's [installation instructions](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Snow_Leopard_Installation_Instructions.pdf).

This means, Snow Leopard does not run on pre-February 2006 Mac minis and runs on any newer products, yet with restrictions (see above). You can check the [specific Intel-based models here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_mini#Specifications_2).

So, you need to know your specific model number or the processor type. Check your processor by clicking the <kbd></kbd> logo in the top left menu bar, and then "About this Mac". You'll find your processor name and speed there.