# Mac OS X can't be installed on this computer - strange error from boot - install of Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, upgrade, osx-leopard

I have an "Intel Core 2 Duo, 1GB RAM" Mac mini.

I am trying to install Mac OS X Snow Leopard. Currently the Mac mini is running Mac OS X Leopard v10.5.8.

While Installing Snow Leopard 10.6.4 from an original Apple install DVD, I got the following message.

From my [previously asked question's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/347808), according to me, it is possible to install Snow Leopard on a Mac mini. What would be the trouble here?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to use an SL DVD that came with another Mac. They often fail to install on Mac models different from the one they were shipped with.

You need to get a Snow Leopard Retail DVD.

Comment: Yess, I am trying to use SL DVD that came with another Mac.

Comment: @sugar Problem solved. Get a retail DVD and it'll work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. I have Snow Leopard installed on my Mac Mini (1.8Ghz, 2GB RAM). I've upgraded from Tiger about 2 years ago, I think. It was relatively painless.

Maybe it's a RAM thing? Or maybe you don't have enough disk space left ( acommon problem with the 80GB default HD).

Comment: I have 80GB hdisk, I made 2 partition. 55+55. One is having Leopard & other is completely blank ( for Snow installation ). what should be done ?

Comment: Since you can repartition during installation, disk space is probably not the issue here.

Comment: @DanielBeck - Once I click next after selecting language, I am getting above error displayed in image & I am not able to select any of the option. It means, all menu items are disabled. I am not able to open disk utility.

Comment: @sugar And that's why the referenced part of answer can't be correct.

Answer (score 0):

You CANNOT use a gray Mac OS X installation DVD that came with another Mac. You have to use the Snow Leopard retail installation DVD.

Comment: How is this better than accepted answer?